# Samsung Galaxy S4 - no adb devices

Tags: adb, samsung-galaxy-s-4

I wanted to install a custom ROM on my old Galaxy S4 I9500. I installed CWM recovery at first with Odin, and it worked really well.

Thereafter, I tried side-loading or pushing the custom ROM using ADB, but it could not find the device.

I tried to install Samsung drivers and reinstalling them but it didn't work.

Any solution to detect the device?

Comment: Please provide some more information. What operating system are you using? Where did you get the adb/fastboot binaries? What version of CWM did you install, and what is the exact error adb gave you?

Comment: Im using Windows 8, I installed adb a while ago so I dont really remember but it was working just before I installed the CWM recovery, the version of CWM is 6.0.3.2.. the error is: device not found.

Comment: Okay. Try disabling and enabling developer mode on the phone, and make sure that the adb checkbox is on. When you connect the phone, does it display a notification saying that USB debugging is enabled? 

Also, when was the last time you rebooted your windows 8 machine?

Comment: did that already nothing happened, and I also rebooted my windows but still.

Comment: Try this on a linux machine, or boot a LiveUSB on your win8 box. It's unclear if this is the phone or comp issue, so we need to bisect the possibilities.

Oh, also try a different usb cable and different port on the comp.

Comment: The notification is not saying that USB debugging is enabled.. eventhough it is enabled

Comment: Hm... Try wiping cache and dalvik, and try with different cables and ports.